# Django 'collectstatic': is it a bad practice to automate it?

Tags: python, django, static, apache2

I have a Django project as a webserver (Apache2) on a Linux machine.
The server needs to periodically analyze some files outside the Django project folder, so I'm running `python3 manage.py collectstatic` to gather all files into my *static* directory.

I couldn't find anything related to this, so I would like to know if is this a Bad practice or if already exist a better way to do this...
Should I add a *cronjob* or *systemd service* to execute `python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput` and automate this process? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: `collectstatic` only collect static files. What do you want to analyze.

Comment: I think cronjob is unnecessary. You can run collectstatic right before restarting apache, so that you can serve the latest static contents

Comment: The same sever receive some images via FTP. The `collectstatic` would be to copy them to the Django project folder. I don't know how to automatically copy a file after receiving it via FTP.